# SWIFT 3: Segue with navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to send some values from one viewcontroller to another. (all embedded in NavigationController). I could make segue with normals viewcontrollers so in general I understand a segue idea. I've to do that in two different ways and got two different problems.

**First way**, segue does right but "two times". I mean after segue (which I want) there is another segue to same controller but without navigation controller and without data I would send. The "back" button on last viewcontroller is returning to AlmostViewController.

Here's code: [image]

**Second way**, Nothing happened,

> ErorCould not cast value of type 'RevisionApp.AlmostViewController'
>   (0x1055d58c0) to 'UINavigationController' (0x107669f18).

Here's code: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first Problem, When using embedded in navigation controller you have don't have to create action function when the button is tapped. Navigation controller does it for you. So things you need to do :

1. Disconnect the function `btnTapped` from the button using storyBoard.
2. Delete or comment the function `btnTapped`(You don't need it).

Comment: @Jakubpawelski Welcome!! Happy to help. I am learning too. Please Upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is line number 18. You are trying to cast `AlmostViewController` to a `UINavigationController`. Directly access like this,

```
let detailController = segue.destination as! AlmostViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as NextViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)